# How to restore stock boot image on uleFone Armor X6 Pro via fastboot?

Tags: fastboot, boot

I have a uleFone Armor X6 Pro on which I intended to install twrp, but made a mistake. Instead of giving the command

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
```

I said

```
fastboot flash boot twrp.img
```

which, I assume, overwrote the boot partition. The device now can only be booted to fastboot - attempting to boot to normal or recovery results in it merely re-booting. I therefore assume that I should fix this by flashing the original boot.img but I do not have it. I have looked at the uleFone website, where I find a link to https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z97JcD1QeH_XkOT30AZkQBUjuqkJH41N which contains "Eu version" and "Non Eu version" each of which eventually contains a file "boot-sign.img" but no "boot.img" If I try flashing either of these "boot-sign.img" fastboot says:

```
Sending 'boot_a' (16384 KB)                        OKAY [  0.534s]
Writing 'boot_a'                                   FAILED (remote: 'image is not a boot image')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

so I'm guessing that this is not a suitable boot image (or maybe it needs a signature to be removed somehow??)

Assuming I need to "fastboot flash boot boot.img", where do I get the boot.img? Or if that asumption is wrong, how else do I recover this device?

I don't have convenient access to a Mac or Windows PC, so answers using Linux are preferred (but not mandatory).